# Force user approval prompt using Google Sign-In Javascript library

Tags: javascript, google-signin

My application is following the server-side flow as described at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow, which provides the client with a one-time code that is forwarded to the server in which the server gets an `access_token` and `refresh_token`.

In previous versions of the Google Sign-In for Javascript library, the developer was able to pass a property `'approval_prompt': 'force'` when setting up the library, to force the approval prompt to appear when the user clicks the Google Sign-In button. This can be very valuable if you need to get a `refresh_token` again, as the one time code grants a `refresh_token` only when an approval prompt is shown to the user.

Previously in the older API i could pass `'approval_prompt': 'force'` during my call to `gapi.signin.render()` to force the prompt. In the newer version of the API (using `gapi.auth2.init()`) it doesn't seem to respect `'approval_prompt': 'force'`. Is it still possible using the newer API in the Javascript library to force the approval prompt using `'approval_prompt': 'force'` or some similar mechanism as in previous versions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking - are you asking if the API from a previous version still works? Do you have reason to expect it won't? Have you tried it yourself and had a problem?

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully clarify what I'm asking

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `'approval_prompt': 'force'` with gapi, you can use `grantOfflineAccess` which will take the parameter into account whereas `gapi.signin.render()` doesn't.

Here is a small authentication example for getting offline access with specified scope & with usage of `'approval_prompt': 'force'` to always request permissions (and eventually get the new refresh token every time)  :

```
<!-- The top of file index.html -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=start" parsetags="explicit" async defer></script>

        <title>Google authentication</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            #customBtn {
                display: inline-block;
                background: white;
                color: #444;
                width: 190px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                border: thin solid #888;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            #customBtn:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            span.label {
                font-family: serif;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            span.icon {
                background: url('https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/g-normal.png') transparent 5px 50% no-repeat;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width: 42px;
                height: 42px;
            }
            span.buttonText {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                padding-left: 42px;
                padding-right: 42px;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
                /* Use the Roboto font that is loaded in the <head> */
                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Google Authentication</h1>
        <hr>

        <div id="gSignInWrapper">
            <span class="label">Sign in with:</span>
            <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="buttonText">Google</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="log"></div>

        <script>

            var auth2;

            function start() {

                gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                        client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
                        scope: 'profile'
                    });
                });
                $('#customBtn').click(function () {

                    auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri' : 'postmessage', 'approval_prompt' : 'force'}).then(signInCallback);

                });
            }

            function signInCallback(authResult) {

                console.log(authResult['code']);

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```